# Will program crash if Unicode data is parsed as Multibyte?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

Okay basically what I'm asking is:

Let's say I use `PathFindFileNameA` on a unicode enabled path. I obtain this path via `GetModuleFileNameA`, but since this api doesn't support unicode characters (italian characters for example) it will output junk characters in that part of the system path.

Let's assume `x` represents a junk character in the file path, such as:

`C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\myfile.sys`

I assume that `PathFindFileNameA` just parses the string with `strtok` till it encounters the last `\\`, and outputs the remainder in a preallocated buffer given str_length - pos_of_last `\\`.

The question is, will the `PathFindFileNameA` parse the string correctly even if it encounters the junk characters from a failed unicode conversion (since the multi-byte API reciprocal is called), or will it crash the program?

Don't answer something like "Well just use `MultiByteToWideChar`", or "Just use a wide-version of the API". I am asking a specific question, and a specific answer would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that you're allowed to do this, so you should consider it to be unsafe.

Comment: @HarryJohnston To be fair, the documentation doesn't mention a lot, about many things. But I'll take your word for it.

Comment: The system works with Unicode data. Why can't you? Are you still supporting Windows 98?

Comment: I don't know why you think somebody would suggest you should *"use `MultiByteToWideChar`"* OR *"use wide char"*. The answer to your specific question is that `PathFindFileNameA` will return `"myfile.sys"` from this broken ANSI string: `"C:\Users\??????\Desktop\myfile.sys"` The `?` character is just `?` character, it is there as substitute for characters which can't be represented.

Comment: Your question contains too many inaccuracies to be answerable. For one, your question title doesn't match the question you are asking. Your description does not indicate that you have an encoding mismatch. (Besides, with the exception of UTF-32, all Unicode encodings are multibyte.) What Microsoft calls *MBCS* can encode characters outside the ASCII range. Code page 1252 ([Latin 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145.aspx)) does contain italian characters. It's unclear why you think that `GetModuleFileNameA` would output *junk characters* - it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score -1):

Why you think that Windows API only do  strtok? I used to hear that all xxA APIs  are  redirected to xxW APIs before win10 are released.

And I think the answer to this question is quite simple. Just write a easy program and then set the code page to what you want.Running that program and the answer goes out.

P.S.:personally I think that GetModuleFileNameA will work correctly even if there are junk characters because Windows will store the Image Name as an UNICODE_STRING internally. And even if you uses MBCS, the junk code does not contain zero bytes, and it will work as usual since it's just using strncpy.

Sorry for my last answer :)

Comment: Err, what changed in Windows 10? Did they finally eliminate the ANSI APIs? Also, individual programs do not set their own code pages. If you call the ANSI APIs, you get the system code page.

Comment: @CodyGray Before Win10 we can simply set breakpoint on Unicode APIs. But I heard that in win10, this trick will not work. So many people think those ANSI family APIs finally get separated.

Comment: @cod: Microsoft appear to be repurposing the ANSI API surface to introduce UTF-8 support, starting with Windows 10 1903. [Use the UTF-8 code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) has some hints towards that. I have no information on how that is implemented internally. It is unlikely that the kernel would understand UTF-8 natively, so I assume that conversions are still involved.